# How to grab values from a multiple select dropdown menu and send them along with POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have this type of multiple select dropdown menu I want to add to my form

```
<form>
...
    <select id="example2" multiple="multiple">
        <div id="otherChoices">
            <optgroup label="Academic" class="blah">
                <option value="Engineering" class="blah">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
                <option value="Life_Sciences">Life Sciences</option>
                <option value="Social Sciences_Sciences">Social Sciences</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Clubs">
                <option value="Event">Event </option>
                <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
                <option value="Performance">Performance</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Personal">
                <option value="Discussion">Discussion</option>
                <option value="Event">Event</option>
                <option value="Food">Food</option>
                <option value="Hangout">Hangout</option>
                <option value="Trip">Trip</option>
            </optgroup>
        </div>
    </select>
</form>
```

But I'm not sure what type of input form this is (it's a bootstrap created form but not of a valid input type), so I'm not sure exactly how to send the parameters via a post request. Currently, I'm using jquery to grab the selected values and and fill in a hidden form. Is there a better way about this?

Comment: The way you've got is working? What's the problem?

Comment: just copy the entire `<select>` into your hidden form and let the browser or jquery do their thing upon submission.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. What do you mean notvalid input type? The select field is a valid input type. Please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a few mistakes in your HTML:
This is the corrected version:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
    <select name="example2[]" id="example2" multiple="multiple" >
        <div id="otherChoices" name="hello">
            <optgroup label="Academic" class="blah">
                <option value="Engineering" class="blah">Engineering</option>
                <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
                <option value="Life_Sciences">Life Sciences</option>
                <option value="Social Sciences_Sciences">Social Sciences</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Clubs">
                <option value="Event">Event </option>
                <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
                <option value="Performance">Performance</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Personal">
                <option value="Discussion">Discussion</option>
                <option value="Event">Event</option>
                <option value="Food">Food</option>
                <option value="Hangout">Hangout</option>
                <option value="Trip">Trip</option>
            </optgroup>
        </div>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

EDIT:
This is what I corrected:

1. I added a name value to the select with square brackets to show its an array
2. I added a method type to the form: method="post"
3. Submit button

You can then access the individual items like this:

```
echo $_POST["example2"][0];
```

EDIT: Sorry I realised this is Node.js That one was for PHP. See this link for how to get post variable in node js:

[How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: i appreciate your answer... GOOD JOB...!

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, it passes an array to the next page, specified in the form's `action` attribute. If one isn't set, it will submit to the current URL.

By default, forms will submit using `GET` unless set the `method` attribute to `post`.

So, change your `<form>` tag to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
```

And give your `select` a `name`, like `name="test_select"`.

And then your `test.php` can look like this:

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
```

(no need for a `?>` closing tag)

This will print the `$_POST` array and you'll see how multiple selects work.